# To display select statement - sql query

Tags: html, sql-server, asp-classic

I have a query that selects `companyName` and `department` from the database. When I display on my website, it will be order by `companyName`.

When I add select `productSold` from the department, my department got separated into 2 records if there are 2 `productSold`. Is there anyway I can display 1 department with 2 records in the table.
Thanks.

My query is as follows:

```
SELECT dbo.CompanyAdd.companyName, 
       dbo.OrderDetails.department,
       dbo.OrderDetails.productSold
FROM   dbo.CompanyAdd 
INNER JOIN
       dbo.OrderDetails
GROUP BY dbo.CompanyAdd.companyName,
       dbo.OrderDetails.department, 
       dbo.OrderDetails.productSold
HAVING (dbo.User2Company.UsrID = 10)
ORDER BY
       dbo.OrderDetails.department;
```

This is my code to check if previous record is same as current.

```
<% dim productSold  
   Do While  Not registerRS.EOF 
     Response.write"<table>" 
     Response.write "<tr>" %> 
     <td height="265.6" width="264.56">
       <%=rS.Fields("companyName")%> <br />
       <%=rS.Fields("department") %><br />
       <%=rS.Fields("productSold") %><br /> 
     </td>      
     <%
      Response.write "</tr>" 
      If r = 4 then r = 1 
      'Next  
        if rS.Fields("productSold") <> productSold then
          Response.write("productSold:" & productSold) 
        end if
      rS.movenext 
   loop  
   Response.write "</table> "  
   rS.close 
   set rS=nothing   
%>
```

Comment: you are getting 1 dept with 2 records, it's just putting the dept on both records, correct? you really can't easily get rid of that in your result set, I would recommend looping through your results and only show the dept for the first record and then the products sold for the 1st and 2nd records.

Comment: So I will have to use nested loop? One to loop until product sold is finished and another till department is done?

Comment: you could do that or just use one loop and check that the department has changed and if it has write it, if not don't write it.

Comment: I have used if rS.Fields("productSold") <> product then Response.write product to compare the current with previous record. But the product is blank. Am I missing something?

Comment: what is product set too?  Can you post your loop process?

Comment: I have made the loop before rS.movenext.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your not setting the variable `productSold` to `rS.Fields("productSold")`. Your also missing an end if before the loop statement.

Try modifying your code to be something like this.

```
<% dim productSold  
   Do While  Not registerRS.EOF 
     Response.write"<table>" 
     Response.write "<tr>" %> 
     <td height="265.6" width="264.56">
       <%=rS.Fields("companyName")%> <br />
       <%=rS.Fields("department") %><br />
       if rS.Fields("productSold") <> productSold then
         Response.write("productSold:" & productSold) 
       end if           
     </td>      
     <%
      Response.write "</tr>" 
      If r = 4 then r = 1 
      'Next  
      if rS.Fields("productSold") <> productSold then
        Response.write("productSold 2:" & productSold) 
      end if
      productSold = rS.Fields("productSold") '<-- Set productSold variable
      rS.movenext 
   loop  
   Response.write "</table> "  
   rS.close 
   set rS=nothing   
%>
```

I added it outside the `if` statement but depending on your logic you may want to set it inside the `if` statement. You commented that you moved the `rS.movenext` before the loop, it has to be before the loop otherwise your recordset would never get to the next record.

Comment: Hi, i tried your code but repeating all the records even when the department remain the same.

Comment: I updated the script slightly, my end if wasn't correct for you.  I also noticed that your writing out the productSold variable in 2 locations.  Are you sure it's writing it the 2nd time when they are the same?  I modified the code to check in both places and added a 2 to the 2nd write statement.

Comment: Thank you. It's what I was trying to get.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on SQL Server 2005+, you could concatenate all same-department products into single product lists, delimiting them e.g. with line separators (depending on whether you prefer `varchar` or `nvarchar` in this case, it could be either `CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)` or `NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10)`).

This site contains plenty of examples of how to concatenate a column of values into a single value. Here's just one of the lot:

- [Simulating group_concat MySQL function in Microsoft SQL Server 2005?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-ms-sql-server-2005/451441#451441)

You can explore the question's *Linked* section to find more similar questions and, consequently, more examples.